# Laravel query is not working with multiple IDs

Tags: laravel

I am trying to fetch multiple rows of selected IDs from db. Here is my controller code

```
$products = new product;
$products = $products->select('products.*', 'categories.category_name')->join('categories', 'products.product_category', '=', 'categories.id');
$products = $products->whereIn('products.id', [$request->list]); //$request->list is post value (12,13)
$products = $products->get();
```

Here `$request->list` is post value which contains 12,13. Mentioned code works fine if I manually type IDs like this.

```
$products = $products->whereIn('products.id', [12,13]);
```

But if I try to call same with variable or  directly with request post then it is returning only one result.

```
$products = $products->whereIn('products.id', [$request->list]); 
//OR
$id = $request->list;
$products = $products->whereIn('products.id', $id);
```

Why it is giving only one result when I use variable, any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$request->list` contains comma separated values, so convert it to an array. Change it as below:

```
$products = $products->whereIn('products.id', explode(',',$request->list));
```

Here is a full query:

```
$products = product::select('products.*', 'categories.category_name')
->join('categories', 'products.product_category', '=', 'categories.id')
->whereIn('products.id',explode(',',$request->list))
->get();
```